# Cldr issue with globalize when implementing in angular cli

Tags: angular, localization, cldr, javascript-globalize

Im trying to create a angular 4 project with L10n support .I'm trying to use [Globalize](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize) library in my project .But im getting a lot of error when compling my project.I dont want to use globalize-webpack-plugin or to change my webpack config file .I installed globalize using`npm install globalize cldr-data`.But when im trying to use globalize in my .ts file like `import Globalize from 'globalize'` im getting error like `cant resolve cldr`.

```js
import { Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as cldr from 'cldrjs';
import Globalize from 'globalize';
var globalize = new Globalize( "en" );
console.log(globalize);
```

```
ERROR in ./~/globalize/dist/globalize.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cldr'
```

Im stuck at this point .Any help is appreciated

Comment: This error is related to AMD. Are you using webpack/babel?

Comment: That Rafael it got solved

Comment: Cool. To help others, it would be great if you could then answer your own question with what you did :)

Comment: I imported the required js like supplementary.js etc in script section of angular-cli.json file

Comment: @dockerrrr could you please post an answer on your own question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add paths to the `globalize` and `cldr` modules in your `tsconfig.json` file like this:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "globalize": [
        "node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize"
      ],
      "globalize/*": [
        "node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/*"
      ],
      "cldr": [
        "node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr"
      ],
      "cldr/*": [
        "node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr/*"
      ],
      "jszip": [
        "node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Reference:
https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular/blob/master/docs/setup-3rd-party-dependencies.md#globalize-registration

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your Webpackconfig file:

```
  resolve: {alias: {'cldr$': 'cldrjs', 'cldr': 'cldrjs/dist/cldr'}}
```